# How to improve Google Pagespeed score for Mobile

Tags: magento2.2.6, pagespeed

We have built a site using Magento 2.2.x version. While we check the Pagespeed of our site in Google Pagespeed insight, we have noticed that the page-speed in mobile showing low score but the page-speed of the desktop showing a higher score compared to the mobile.

Please see the below screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Why is that the page speed score is too low in mobile even-though the page speed of desktop is higher?

Please share your thoughts and help me to get a better speed score in mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps to increase the page score:

1. Make sure that js and css compressed in the backend.
2. Check whether you have minified js and css in the backend.
3. Use [GT metrix](https://gtmetrix.com/) and check what are the images are not optimized and optimized those images.
4. Make sure that you have added gzip compression and leverage browser caching in the `.htaccess` file.
5. Use CDN for static images.
6. Use `varnish` and `redis` for frontend and backend cache.

Comment: I have done all the above points but still, we are getting the low page speed score. Could you please give me some more insights?

Comment: Also, I'm getting different scores randomly. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please implement AMP concept for mobile version that boost the website speed in mobile. because currently maximum traffic comes from mobile device.

I have recently implement this concept in my two Magento projects, and get good result.

For more details click [here](https://www.ampproject.org/)

Comment: can you explain how to implement it magento projects.

Answer (score 0):

We are facing the same issue with magento 2.4