# Magento 2 - Page Speed Insights / Lighthouse Audits vs webpagetest site performance

Tags: pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I noticed recently the Google page speed insights has improved somewhat, shows a lot more information however is harsh especially it seems for Magento 2 (I can get 98 so far from other non Magento 2 websites).

I am used to being able to getting Page Speed insights scores into the 80s and 90s with some light tweaks although felt this was just ticking check boxes (deferring resource, using optimised images, gzip and caching resources, avoiding redirects etc) and now it seems a bit more real based on performance of the site. Now however I am looking at scores of 30 ish.

I'm concerned as although testing my sites do not feel overly slow I have always thought Magento 2 seems a bit weighty especially on the JavaScript side with a lot going on client side on page load slowing the "time to interactive" that shows with 3G mobile audit to around 15 seconds.

I have recently took a few steps to improve including no longer merging JavaScript as this seems to make my page size considerable larger i think about 5MB down to 2MB was what I witnessed. Deferring loading of images. Further improvements . I am using already HTTP2 especially since dropping merging of JS there are a lot of separate resources this may help. Using WEBP for example instead of JPEG etc for catalog images.

I'm posting this question as want to know if everyone else is as bad and what measures you have taken to improve these poor scores?

I guess at the end of the day it is all relative and everyone will get worse scores I'm just slightly concerned Magento may be hit harder than other eCommerce platforms and not sure on the SEO side of this but would like to at least try and improve as this cannot be good... Further tests on competitor sites shows some sites still in the 60-70 range this seem to be on much lighter eCommerce platforms.

below are the screen for reference for performance screens comparing with webpage test and lighthouse (googlepagespeed insights)

[image]
below lighthouse
[image]

some one said like below after installing below link extension it increased but those link not working 
 https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/
any one give suggestion it will help for me

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful info, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: We would like to analyze your data.  Suggestions will be provided to improve query processing speed.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked before although in different ways.

What you are seeing is the same as everyone else.

Magento 2 doesn't score high in certain areas because of how it is structured. For example require js decides what content to show.

Suggestions

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/255766/70343

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/273133/70343